# Error Severity in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to log the **Severity of Error** in **OnErrorCode** event handler in **SSIS**.

Severity can be like : **Info**, **Warning**, **Critical**

I am just curious if anybody knows about how to get this information to log in EventHandler in SSIS and provide any URL which can be useful in looking for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you referring to something that is internal to SSIS, or is this some bespoke classification?

In SSIS, there is an **OnInformation** event and **OnWarning** event in the same manner that there is an **OnError** event. Maybe you could consider logging out from these events as well as the **OnError** event.

As far as I can tell, only OnError will fail your package, unless there is something I am missing.